# JPA - Cascade Delete failing

Tags: jpa, cascading-deletes

I have Table A ...

id:bigint - primary key NOT NULL
name:string

... and i have Table B that has a foreign key to table A ...

id:bigint - primary key NOT NULL
name:string
a_id:bigint - foreign key to table A.id NOT NULL

When i generate the jpa entities and jpacontrollers the foreign key looks like this in Table A entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<B> bList;
```

and it looks like this in table B entity

```
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private A aId;
```

However when delete an entry from table A that has a linked entry in table B that should be cascade deleted, it hits an error in the table A jpacontroller destroy method complaining that it cannot remove the a_id from table B as the field is not null (i.e. it is trying to remove the link but preserve the record rather than cascade delete). The code in the destroy method in the jpa controller where it hits this error is here

```
        List<B> bList = a.getBList();
        for (B bListB : bList) {
            bListB.setAId(null);
            bListB = em.merge(bListB);
        }
```

if i remove that code, the cascade delete works, but when the jpa controller is next regenerated i will lose my changes.

could someone advise what am i doing wrong here please.

thank you.

Comment: You should check your database tables cascade constraints

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi This is the constraint for the foreign key in question.              ALTER TABLE public.B
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_B_a_id FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
      REFERENCES public.a(id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;                                          The cascade delete works ok when i remove the code from the jpacontroller so the database is allowing cascade deletes. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I guess you need `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead of `ON DELETE NO ACTION`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no that didn't fix it. It still throws an exception in the jpacontroller _Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "a_id" violates not-null constraint_

Comment: To be precise, the exception is thrown on **entityManager.getTransaction().commit()'** the code lines I listed are the cause though as the commit succeeds if i remove them

Comment: Cascade delete have to work without listed code. Delete it. What exception will you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213852/discussion-between-alex-valuiskyi-and-r-l).

Comment: Sorry could you explain further?

Comment: I hadn't re-generated the jpacontroller, when i did so, the offending lines didn't get re-generated and so the db fix suggested by alex worked. thank you. i have up-arrowed the solution.